# Flex rows' height add up to parent bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a web that has exactly the screen's height (no scrolling), using Bootstrap 4 and flex containers. So far, the structure was holding up, until I decided to try inserting tall images.

The image scales to fit the width and it exceeds the height of the screen (I dont want this).

I want everything to fit in the screen without scrolling: this means, the image has to fill all the available height, without starving other rows of height (e.g. the footer). I've tried specifying `height:100%` on all parent containers and on the image as well (using bootstrap's `h-100` class), but I've encountered two problems:

- the image changes the aspect ratio
- the added height of rows inside a column exceeds the total parent height, so the total height ends up being larger than the screen, and some elements go off the screen.

I haven't come up with a way of telling child elements of a column (rows in this case), to have a total height of 100% without manually specifying each row's height. I think that would solve the issue.

The whole structure is basically as follows (I've removed unnecessary elements):

```html
<body id="page-top" class="bg-light">
  <div id="page-content-wrapper" class="min-vh-100 p-0 d-flex flex-column overflow-hidden h-100">
    <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-row overflow-auto flex-fill justify-content-center pt-3 pb-3 h-100">

      <div class="container flex-column d-flex col-7 mr-3 ml-3 h-100">
        <!-- play area -->
        <div class="row flex-fill h-100">
          <div class="section-div flex-grow-1 flex-column d-flex h-100" id="play-area">
            <div class="row flex-grow-1">
              <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid d-flex w-100">
                <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column">
                  <h1 class="display-4 pb-2">title</h1>
                  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/93/Burj_Khalifa.jpg" style="object-fit:contain">
                  <hr class="mb-3" />
                  <p>
                    some more text
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="height:100px">
              <div class="row mt-auto justify-content-md-center">
                <div class="col-md-auto text-center">
                  <p>some text at bottom</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And a JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/prx4k76t/

Comment: Tell your problem in a single line. ??

Comment: I'd like the image in the example not to grow past the screen height

Comment: Do you want to say that the text is overflowing?